# How do you remove results from searches in bing?

Tags: bing

I want to remove results from a query in bing. But when I use the NOT, which I have read is to remove searches. But whenever I do use NOT it just includes the keyword I am trying to remove.

For example, when I type keyword1 and NOT keyword2.Results starting showing up for keyword2. NOT doesn't seem very effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just:

```
keyword1 -keyword2
```

This seems to work on a test for searching on:

> [Windows 7 -amazon -wikipedia](http://www.bing.com/search?q=windows%207%20-wikipedia%20-amazon&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=windows%207%20-wikipedia%20-amazon&sc=8-28&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=870dd4afc1ca4b148aa9a39b9e44daa4)

Versus just plain search for “[Windows 7](http://www.bing.com/search?q=windows%207&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=windows%207&sc=8-9&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=2f7d14958d2a489085477a1684f576c0)”.

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine for me; when I type `bing singer` Bing Crosby results fill the page, but `bing singer NOT crosby` omits the Bing Crosby pages. You could also try `bing singer -crosby` instead of using `NOT`.

Note that using `NOT` or `-` does not prevent the keyword from showing up in the related searches.

Comment: Can you give me copy of your search results using that query? I tried it with the NOT operator and it still includes the results for 'bing crosby'. Although, I already found out that using '-' would work. I'm I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @user246694 [Here](http://imgur.com/a/ewGzp) ya go. You need to make sure you have the space, but apart from any syntax errors like that, I don't know why it wouldn't be working for you.

Comment: Can somebody give me there search results? I don't get how this is working. My results come up with Bill Crosby Wikipedia page as the 1st hit, even with the NOT operator.